# Elastic search query for multiple where conditions in java code

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search and i need help for below scenario

SQL Query:

```
select * from <TABLE> where column1 = <value1> or column1 > <value2> or column1 < <value3> or column1 like '%value%';
```

I want the elastic search equivalent query and java code for the same

i tried 
`QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(keyToUse, value.split(';')))`

Note: I get values with ";" separated.

But above query is equivalent to below sql

```
select * from <table> where column1=<value1> or column2=<value2> ...
```

everything is equal operator but i want to apply the conditions based on input.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not quite understand the query you want to produce. Elasticsearch does not use SQL. And do want to split some list or have some column value as parameter to a field comparison?

Comment: You cant do sql like  joins in elasticsearch. The maximum you can do this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html

Comment: @P.J.Meisch, I have given sql just to understand what i need in elastic search. so my question is how to write elastic search query in java code for the sql query given

Comment: @Shubh, I don't want to do any joins here, i want to know how to write elastic search query in java code for the given sql query.